# What does Observable.from([true]) do?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Looking through my code base, I've noticed that a previous developer, when creating a function to transform one model to another, commonly uses the following code:

`property: Observable.from([true]);`

What does this accomplish exactly and why can't the value just be set to `true`?

According to [the documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-from), the `from` operator:

> Creates an Observable from an Array, an array-like object, a Promise,
>   an iterable object, or an Observable-like object.

Why should we use the `from` operator if the array is only ever 1 value?

Comment: I mean, if it's always going to be a single value, why use an array?

Comment: @Pytth How about just setting it to a Boolean?

Comment: if you are super sure its going to be only one value, use `Observable.of(true)` then.

Comment: It's really equivalent. the only possible value in doing that is if you want to add another value, it's an array already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing, these are conventions followed by some teams or individuals, where

1. members are initialised to determine type and initial/default value, here `property` is of type `Observable<boolean>`, which means this member data is calculated asynchronously (and is most likely to be used with an `async` pipe in the HTML incase of angular).
2. for the sake of maintenance and understandability, one could use an array instead of a single value, just to indicate that this property emits **multiple** values instead of a single value. (Just informs developers to be aware of this during the design or implementation)